# JSON Parsing Specific Values

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying make an GET request and then parse the body response, which is in JSON, in order to print out individual values of the body.

In this example I have a helpdesk ticket and I want to get the individual tickets subject field. I can get the response and the ticket with all values included (shown below) but I can not specify to only print the `subject` field.

```js
function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info.tickets);
  }
}
```

This first section works fine and I get the following response.

```
[ { deleted: false,
    status: 1,
    tags: [],
    subscribers: [ [Object] ],
    _id: '5d9bd7cbce54bb059eaa8917',
    subject: 'Laptop Slow',
    group:
     { members: [Array],
       sendMailTo: [],
       public: false,
       _id: '5d976626c2547f37e092b2ee',
       name: '02719',
       __v: 2 },
    type:
     { priorities: [Array],
       _id: '5d9247605ab9ee056952fe39',
       name: 'Issue',
       __v: 2 },
    priority:
     { overdueIn: 2880,
       htmlColor: '#29b955',
       _id: '5d9247689701551f588adf76',
       name: 'Normal',
       migrationNum: 1,
       default: true,
       __v: 0,
       durationFormatted: '2 days',
       id: '5d9247689701551f588adf76' },
    issue: '<p>Hi My laptop is really slow</p>\n',
    date: '2019-10-08T00:26:51.301Z',
    comments: [],
    notes: [],
    attachments: [],
    history: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    owner:
     { _id: '5d978f80f5d1fd428f32570b',
       username: 'test-customer',
       email: 'test@mailtest.com',
       fullname: 'Test-Customer',
       title: '',
       role: [Object] },
    uid: 1002,
    __v: 2,
    closedDate: null } ]
```

However, when I try and go one field further (i.e. `info.tickets.subject`), I receive `undefined` for the `subject` value.

```js
function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info.tickets.subject);
  }
}

undefined
```

Comment: `info.tickets` is an *array*, not a single value. You probably want `info.tickets[0]` or any other index.

Comment: Yah, I should have mentioned that I tried that, but I still get undefined for any index besides [0] which returns the entire ticket.

Comment: That's because there's only 1 ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Data is an array in your database query u are using find you should use findOne then you code work properly.

For find Query

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info.tickets[0].subject);
  }
}
```

For findOne Query

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info.tickets.subject);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

info.tickets is an array, you can not access as a object.

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info.tickets[0].subject);
  }
}
```